# How can I calculate CSS pixels from resolution?

Tags: css

I am making a web application that has some very specific interactivity features that are quite screen size dependent. I have planned to create 2 versions of said features, one for desktop and one for mobile.

This brings the issue of targeting screen size. I've decided to use the Samsung Galaxy Note as the highest screen size I will be supporting for the mobile version of these features. However, for this I need to find out the **CSS pixel** size of this screen.

How can I find this out if I know that the display is 13.46 cm (5.29 in) and 800x1280 px (285 ppi)?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS Pixel Device-Width can be calculated by dividing the Pixel Width by the CSS Pixel Ratio, and rounding it to the nearest integer.

List here:

http://www.canbike.org/CSSpixels/

Answer (score 0):

If you know that its dimensions are 800x1280px, then you can target this device (and all that are smaller) with this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    *your styles here*
}
```

Also add this to the `<head>` section of your pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: The problem is that these features are image heavy - by designing for the CSS pixel size I sacrifice quality for loading times, which I believe is more important for this project.

Answer (score 0):

for mobile device you can use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height" >
```

and use device width like

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* For general iPad layouts */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts only */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts only */
}
```